# differentiate between the solid balls and the un-solid balls with same colors(play pool )

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, pycharm, opencv3.0, object-detection

im creating a pool ball assistance and to proceed in this application, i should at the first step to detect the balls on the table, i had so far detected the balls and also i made a system to differentiate between the balls colors

the Question : i wanted to know a algorithm, a way or an idea to differentiate between the solid balls and the stripes balls with the same colors  as shown in the figures

[image: all the balls]

[image: my target]

[image: my last stage output ( Recent progress)]

Important Note : im not searching for any type of codes i just wanted any resources or ideas or articles in such this step (detects solid Vs stripes balls )

thanks in advance